# How to build an app with an existing apk signature

Tags: android, sqlite, apk, android-install-apk

I compiled a project (that contains a sqlite db) using a pc that I have not access to that no more. People used that and inserted records to the db. I don't have any access to their tablets. I made a mistake and i have sent them the apk was in `bin` directory. I changed the program, I want to tell them to update their apps but when they try to replace app, android doesn't let them. So i have to sign my apk as same as the signature of the apk i made on that computer.
What should i do ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's not much you can really do if you don't have access to the old signature. This is a *good* thing, since you wouldn't want anyone else to access it, modify, and upload it somewhere. If your users uninstall the app first, they can then install the new one, but that's about it.

Comment: If they uninstall it, what would happen to their databases ? Unfortunately I can't access their tablets and backup data.

Comment: They would be reset to an initial install. Sucks, I know.

Comment: It seems I have to pay penalty this month :D !! Thanks for your help guy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have forgotten my keystore password and I want to install my apk on Google Play. What do I do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871918/i-have-forgotten-my-keystore-password-and-i-want-to-install-my-apk-on-google-pla)

Comment: @Geobits you should add your comments as an answer, so the OP can accept it.

Comment: Now If I use that computer and compile project again, Does it work ?

Comment: Maybe. If the compile environment hasn't changed and it's still using the same debug key, it should work. Using the debug key permanently is probably not the best way to go, though. If you can, just transition to a real key and be careful not to lose it.

Comment: Thank you so much ! You learned me many things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comments:

There's not much you can really do if you don't have access to the old signature. It sounds like you're talking about the debug signature. As you found out, this varies from machine to machine, and if you don't have access to the old machine, it's just **gone**.

This is *normally* a good thing for security reasons. If it was possible to recover your key, anyone could do it. Then they could maliciously modify the app and upload it as a replacement.

As you've also found out, Android won't let you install an update that has a different signature than the currently installed version. If your users completely uninstall the app, they will then be able to install the new one. That's definitely inconvenient, and a customer service headache, but there's not any other way to do it.

Note that the users will lose any databases, etc, that they had in the app. It will act as a fresh install, since that's what it is.

Theoretically, *rooted* users could back up their old databases/preferences with any number of utilities and restore them later. In practice, even most users that *can* do this won't bother with it.