# i lost my debug Keystore file

Tags: java, android, keystore, android-keystore

i was created an app and released without specific Keystore file. i use default debug keystore file... in fact after writing my code i just published it from bin folder... now i changed my laptop and my OS. i have the same code and same project in eclipse but when i change my code and Android Versioncode it seems eclipse creates another debug keystore and my app cant update. how i can recover the same debug Keystore file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have forgotten my keystore password and I want to install my apk on Google Play. What do I do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871918/i-have-forgotten-my-keystore-password-and-i-want-to-install-my-apk-on-google-pla)

Comment: You have to have access to your keystore file. See the answer that I've given before. And you should always use a proper keystore file that you generate for yourself, not the auto-generated one.

Comment: You really shouldn't be distributing (for real use) an app signed with a debug certificate.  For one thing, it probably has a short expiration time which will cause your users problems.  For another, a serious distributor like google play would reject it out of hand.  Consider this mistake a wakeup call to start over with a proper release key, before you get even more users stuck with a broken version.

Answer (score 1):

You published your app to Google Play store directly from /bin ?

Can you give us a link to your app ( just out of curiosity here ) .

But besides that , long story short you can't update your app since you've lost your keystore.

Keystores are unique and with that said they can't be reproduced ( anyone welcomed to say otherwise ).

The only option I see here is to unpublish your app , change your package name and republish it . But take into consideration you will loose your current users.

Please for the future when you build an app. use Android Tools -> Export Signed Application .

Also look into Proguard for obfuscation : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: my app is not published in google play... i just published by a website... but my problem is that my users cant update my app and they should reinstall old version...

Comment: Sorry bro' , there is no other option. It's better if you do it sooner . That way any new users will install the app with your new certificate. But as Chris said debug keystores have short life span. So your current users are going down a bad road anyway.

Comment: Nothing you can do if you don't have your keystore, you will need to start over (like everyone says).  This is common.