# Have done an Android App Update - But don't have original private key

Tags: android, updates, private-key, submission, codesignkey

We built an app for Android 3 years ago.  We need to submit the update to the app, but we don't have the private key that was used in the original app (the one that we're updating. Our original developer is nowhere to be found).

How can we get around this?!  I don't want to submit the app through a separate developer account and I really need this new version to be accessible to the thousands of people who have downloaded version 1.0.

Anything you can do to help would be appreciated SA compadres.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Ben

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have forgotten my keystore password and I want to install my apk on Google Play. What do I do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871918/i-have-forgotten-my-keystore-password-and-i-want-to-install-my-apk-on-google-pla)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do:

- Change package name
- Create your new keystore and sign it
- Send it as new application (with the same name)
- Hide previous application

There is no other way. If you've lost your key there is no real way to identify you as a developer of this app.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot make it unless RSA is cracked.