# Application Keystore missing

Tags: android, keystore

i want to upload a updated application on play store , but unfortunately application keystore is missing. When i create a new keystore , it gives error during signing that application.

Is there any way to retrieve my previously used keystore from uploaded apk file , or any other way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have forgotten my keystore password and I want to install my apk on Google Play. What do I do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871918/i-have-forgotten-my-keystore-password-and-i-want-to-install-my-apk-on-google-pla)

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Straight, Unfortunately there is no way you can retrieve your lost key-store

Thanks