# Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect android studio

Tags: android

Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect error while generating signed apk.Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key ......... from store "...............jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Comment: Seems you entered a wrong alias/username and password. Make sure both of them are right.

Comment: both of them 200% right...

Comment: Check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034899/how-to-retrieve-key-alias-and-key-password-for-signed-apk-in-android-studiomigr

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your keystore password. Also make sure you are using the correct keystore for your app.

Comment: Try to check that you are using correct keystore.jks.