# I am trying to enabling Google Play App Signing but geting error while generating .pem file

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, keystore

i am a unity game developer. i am trying to get .pem file from keystore through command prompt in order to enable app signing and commmand is

```
C:\Users\admin19>java -jar C:\Users\admin19\Desktop\pepk.jar --keystore= F:\Key
Store\abc.keystore --alias=abc --output=C:\Users\admin
19\Desktop\output\key.pem --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c94656756df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c0
9ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8fghhjkcef2kk7558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9d
e6a
```

i press enter after typing this to cmd.

it ask for keystore **passward** !!! i enter.... then it ask for **alias passward** !! i enter which is same as keystore passward.. but it is giving error : `no key for alias : [aliasname]`..what should i do.. plz help

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the suggestions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034899/how-to-retrieve-key-alias-and-key-password-for-signed-apk-in-android-studiomigr).

> To get the Key Alias: I copied the keytool.exe and my keystore file into `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin` folder. Then from command prompt I wrote: `keytool -list -v -keystore <name>.keystore` It will also ask for keystore password then. Then it will show you the key alias and Certificate fingerprints and other info.

It was also mentioned that if you have the keystore password, keytool might be able to list the aliases.