# Android Key password is missing however i do have keystore password

Tags: android, google-play, sha, android-keystore

I am into a big issue. I have android key store password, but key password it is saying as 'Cannot recover Key'. When i create new key app is signed, but it is not uploaded to play store. It is showing SHA not matching

My recent activities involve

Android studio update Please specify is it because of this.

[image: Key Missing screenshot]

I have also attached screenshot please see missing part and let me know how it can be found. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve Key Alias and Key Password for signed APK in android studio(migrated from Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034899/how-to-retrieve-key-alias-and-key-password-for-signed-apk-in-android-studiomigr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my keystore file into C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin folder. Then from the command prompt, I wrote: keytool -list -v -keystore . keystore It will also ask for keystore password then. Then it will show you the key alias and Certificate fingerprints and other info.
You can find more answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034899/how-to-retrieve-key-alias-and-key-password-for-signed-apk-in-android-studiomigr) also on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-recover-a-lost-Android-signing-key-password)

Comment: It shows info but not key password. I want to know key password.

Comment: Can you please help me if i have idea.log file but the password in it is showing *******

Answer (score 1):

These are the ways you can find our your password

1. From the logs: If you have your logs intact, then you can find the password in the Android Studio log files : Go to ~/Library/Logs -> AndroidStudio ->idea.log.1 and search for Search for "Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password" and you can see the key password. (or simply search for a password using Ctrl + F)
2. From the taskArtifacts: You can retrieve the password from the taskArtifacts in your .gradle directory. Look in .gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin. This doesn't seem to work for newer versions of Gradle (2.10 and above).

It really worked for me. Thanks