# No key with alias 'key0' found in keystore

Tags: java, android

My app is already published in Play Store when I will this app updates then Generate Signed Bundle/APK then I will Choose existing path but "No key with alias  'key 0' found in keystore"  this message is shown:

> Note:
>   No key with alias 'key0' found in keystore E:\SUMONcse\ALLCSEPROGRAM\DEVOLOPER.COM\ALL JAVA.COM\ANDROID.COM\GooglePlayStore\Licens\LicenceCalculator\Licencs.jks

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Your app is already published in Play Store or you're publishing this for the first time?

Comment: My app is already published in Play Store.

Comment: Can i know you are write key alias key0 or select the key alias by ...(three doth in right side)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Generate Signed Bundle APK then select your key patha -> key store password -> then select key alias from drop down -> key password -> v1 signed apk.

Now i think you can generate signed apk.

Answer (score 5):

1.Go to Path/Jdk_version/bin/  and run the following command to list the content of your keystore file (and alias name):

`keytool -v -list -keystore .keystore`

2.You will then be asked for you keystore password . Enter it and you will get your detail.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are entering the right alias and passwords?

However, when I forgot my alias (when I wanted to update published app), this saved my life (the most popular answer, by gkemp):

[How to retrieve Key Alias and Key Password for signed APK in android studio(migrated from Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034899/how-to-retrieve-key-alias-and-key-password-for-signed-apk-in-android-studiomigr)

Comment: Yes,i am sure entering the right alias and passwords. But this message is show "No key with alias 'key0' found in keystore"

Answer (score 0):

Find the Key Alias along with certificate details to check if key0 is your real alias name given. Use the following command:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore keystore.jks
```

You'll be asked for keystore password and after that, you can get the details.