# Android key password is missing

Tags: android-studio, signed-apk

I'm using the Android Studio 4.1.1 on MacBook, the AS has been updated several times.

I checked [How to retrieve Key Alias and Key Password for signed APK in android studio(migrated from Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034899/how-to-retrieve-key-alias-and-key-password-for-signed-apk-in-android-studiomigr), but it's not working, there is no AndroidStudio log files under the /Library/Logs directory.

**How can I find the password?**

[image]

Comment: I don't think it works anymore, technically it is almost impossible to retrieve the password once you've lost it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the password. Thanks god!