# Right password causes password verification failed error android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, passwords, key, apk

I tried to generate APK in Android Studio. I received "Password verification failed" message. I tried solution from here [I have forgotten my keystore password and I want to install my apk on Google Play. What do I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871918/i-have-forgotten-my-keystore-password-and-i-want-to-install-my-apk-on-google-pla/43007357#43007357)
Even if I use right password I still get an error.

Comment: If you have the project and have not published a single version of your app, then just generate a new key and sign your apk with it.

Comment: If it says you have the wrong password, you most likely do.